# Как при помощи регулярного выражения разделить строку по пробелам на знаки и числа?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно чтобы строка типа "+ 5   7" делилась на знак, число, число. Знак любой, число любое. Я пишу вот так:

```
String[] strArr = s.split(" ");
```

но этот код не срабатывает если между элементами несколько пробелов.

Comment: Не имели вы ввиду reverse polish calculation? В таком случае вам надо прибегнуть к другому варианту решения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
 String[] strArr = "+   5   7".split("\\s+");
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
```

`\s` - любой space character

`+` - от одного до бесконечного кол-ва повторов

ну и в java нужно экранировать `\` в регулярках, по этому `\\`

---

Неплохой ресурс для тестирования регулярок:

https://regex101.com/r/N1kUnk/1

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: @Makaroni нет проблем, обращайтесь